# HTTP PUT header not working with Angular 2

Tags: angular, http, put

I'm facing a problem with **Angular 2**, Indeed, I need to send a **PUT** Http request with **Authorization** header but it's not working.

However it's work perfectly with **DELETE**, **POST** and **GET** (with exactly the same code).

**The request**

```
private header = new Headers();
// [...]
launchPutRequest(): Promise<any> {
        const url = 'http://myurl.com/';
        this.header = new Headers();
        this.header.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

        return this.http.put(url, { headers: this.header })
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                return response.json().msg as any;
            });
    }
```

According this image, I suppose that header was malformed, but why only with **PUT** ?

[image: Header PUT request]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably getting an error because the signature of a `put` request is:

```
(url: string, body: any, option?: RequestOptionsArgs)
```

You are providing:

```
(url, options)
```

If you aren't using a `body` parameter, I'd recommend changing your http call to:

```
return this.http.put(url, null, { headers: this.header })
```

Hope that helps.